# Symfony: could not find driver in doctrine

Tags: postgresql, symfony, docker, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm unable to connect to pgsql from my symfony app, receiving this error:

> An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver

I got the driver installed and enabled in php.ini, got my doctrine db configuration, i don't know what's missing.

PHP Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7-fpm-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add build-base

RUN apk add postgresql postgresql-dev \
  && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
  && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql

RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache

COPY php/opcache.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache.ini
COPY php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini

WORKDIR /var/www/app

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm","--nodaemonize"]
```

php.ini: [Click here](https://justpaste.it/1m803)

My php.ini is the same as [the official one](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/php.ini-production) but with the `extension=pdo_pgsql` enabled

phpinfo():

[image: phpinfo]

doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
        server_version: '11.5'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - ${DB_PORT}:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www/app
  web:
    image: nginx:1.15.3-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www/app
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - ${NGINX_PORT}:80
    depends_on:
      - php
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

**UPDATE:**

After further investigation it seem like the problem isn't with the server configuration but with the symfony config.I still couldn't fix it, but i tried to connect to the database using the following and it worked:

```
$myPDO = new PDO('pgsql:host=postgres;dbname=app', 'app', 'app123');
$result = $myPDO->query("SELECT * FROM test");
```

In my doctrine library (vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php) it attempts to connect in a similar way by calling the parent constructor(which is PDO):

```
parent::__construct('pgsql:host=postgres;dbname=app', 'app', 'app123');
```

But this one fails...

Comment: where do you get the error? Executing a symfony command or from a web page?

Comment: by running php bin/console make:migration

Comment: if you run php -m can you see pdo and pgsql modules enabled?

Comment: yes, they are..

Comment: In php.ini -> https://justpaste.it/1m803 pgsql extension has comment

Comment: extension=pdo_pgsql

;extension=pgsql

Comment: At the time i pasted it wasn't but i can assure you, it is now